# Standalone chess problem solver for Android

Tags: problems, android

Which android app can:

- Solve chess problems *without internet connection as well*.
- Support manually edit board according to the problem.
- Ideally this app should allow a person to step back on any move and also provide hints on the next move.

This app is for a person who is a novice in chess, so he could try to solve the problems from the book he reads.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [Droidfish](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.petero.droidfish&hl=en) ?

It runs stock Fish engine + you can edit positions.

Answer (score 2):

There are several good options:

- [`iChess`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.analysis) - which is a Chess puzzles app and works without internet.
- [`Analyze This`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.analysis) - which can be used to set up a board position from the book and move back and forth, save and make a collection.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of the aforementioned Apps.

- [`Chess OCR`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kgroth.chessocr&hl=en) - is the best app which can make task easier of automatically scanning Chess board diagram from a book and transferring to above Chess Apps,